# How arraylist operate and is reused in subsets algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I do not understand how ArrayList operate in this problem.

This is a algorithm for the question called "Subsets" from leetcode.

It basically outputs all the subsets of given array.

For example, if [1,2,3] is given array, then the output should be [[],[1],[2],[3],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]

This is an algorithm for this question, but I do not understand how arraylist work in this code.

```
import java.util.*;

class Subsets {

  public static List<List<Integer>> findSubsets(int[] nums) {
    List<List<Integer>> subsets = new ArrayList<>();
    // start by adding the empty subset
    subsets.add(new ArrayList<>());
    for (int currentNumber : nums) {
      // we will take all existing subsets and insert the current number in them to create new subsets
      int n = subsets.size();
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // create a new subset from the existing subset and insert the current element to it
        List<Integer> set = new ArrayList<>(subsets.get(i));
        set.add(currentNumber);
        subsets.add(set);
      }
    }
    return subsets;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = Subsets.findSubsets(new int[] { 1, 3 });
    System.out.println("Here is the list of subsets: " + result);

    result = Subsets.findSubsets(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
    System.out.println("Here is the list of subsets: " + result);
  }
}
```

The exact code part that I am stuck

```
        int n = subsets.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                List<Integer> set = new ArrayList<>(subsets.get(i));
                set.add(currentNumber);
                subsets.add(set);
            }
        }
```

Say n is 2 and currentNumber is 2 as well. In that literation, I think it just creates [2],[2] instead of [2],[1,2] since every inner loop iteration, it creates a new ArrayList and has a same value as currentNumber. I do not understand where [1,2] is from.

Can anyone explain how it outputs [2], [1,2] in second outer literation or where I do not understand?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to see what it *actually* does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand where the `[1]` comes from, we start with the first iteration:

`subsets.add(new ArrayList<>());` adds the empty list to the set;

so, if `currentNumber` is `1` (and size of set is 1 too), it will add `1` to a copy of the empty list from the set (`get(0)`), resulting in `[1]` which is then added to the set.

Now we have the condition posted in question: the set is `[[],[1]]`, size 2 (`n = 2`) and next number will be `2`(`currentNumber = 2`).

---

`subsets` has two elements (`n == 2`): the empty list, and a list containing just `1` (from previous iteration).

`subsets = [[], [1]]`

Now,

iteration `i = 0`, is adding `2` to a copy of the empty list (`get(0)`) and adding the result (`[2])` to `subsets`;

iteration `i = 1`, is adding `2` to a copy of `[1]` (`get(1)`), result `[1,2]` is added to `subsets`.

`subsets` now is `[],[1],[2],[1,2]` - next iteration will add `3` to a copy of every one of that four lists and add the resulting 4 lists to `subsets`.

Key of that algorithm is `new ArrayList<>(subsets.get(i))` which is creating a new list containing the elements of the list already in the set - a clone. Otherwise the end result would contain the same list repeated (with same content).

Comment: @Happydoodle What about it don't you understand? Do you understand that `get(0)` returns `[]` and `get(1)` returns `[1]`? Do you understand that `[]` is cloned and then has `2` inserted into it yielding `[2]`? And that `[1]` is cloned and then has `2` inserted into it yielding `[1,2]`? Do you understand that the clones are added to `subsets`, so that its size doubles every iteration? Something else?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I still do not understand how 2 is added to [1], result [1,2] when literation i = 1. literation i = 1, It still generates new arraylist in that literation, but where and how [1] comes from?

Comment: `new ArrayList<>(Collection c)` creates a new ArrayList with the elements in the original Collection. So `new ArrayList<>(subsets.get(i))` creates a new list with a copy of everything that was in `subsets.get(i)`, which was `[1]`. Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-

Comment: make so sense!! new ArrayList<>(Collection c)! I appreciate it so much ! @Welbog

Comment: please also consider Scott Hunters [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66188852/how-arraylist-operate-and-is-reused-in-subsets-algorithms#comment117017991_66188852) about debugger - it can be very helpful , not only for finding bugs